# How do assign an interval of values to a variable in order to use them in a function?

Tags: equation-solving, system-variables, numerical-value, intervals

From my code (below) I have K1 and K2 set to zero in order to test this numerical method.  However, K1 is on an interval from 0 to 32, and K2 is on an interval from 0 to 8.  I would like to know if there is a way to set these intervals to the associated variables, so that it will run the program for the interval itself.  That way I don't have to run a combination of 32 or 8 separate calculations, etc.

Here is my code pasted directly from the nb.

```
Subscript[x, 0] := 0; Subscript[y, 0] := 1;
Subscript[u, 3] := 0; h := 0.1;
Subscript[K, 1] := 0; Subscript[K, 2] := 0
x[n_] := (Subscript[x, n] = Subscript[x, 0] + n h);
y[n_] := (Subscript[y, n ] = Subscript[y, 0] + n h);
Table[x[n], {n, 0, 5}];
Table[y[n], {n, 0, 5}]

f[n_] := (Subscript[f, 
    n] = -Subscript[K, 1] Subscript[x, 
      n] + -Subscript[K, 2] Subscript[y, n]);
Table[f[n], {n, 0, 5}]

System = {Subscript[u, 
    0] == {1/
      80 (-27 h Subscript[f, 0] - 102 h Subscript[f, 1] - 
        72 h Subscript[f, 2] - 42 h Subscript[f, 3] + 
        3 h Subscript[f, 4] + 80 Subscript[u, 3])}, 
   Subscript[u, 
    1] == {1/
      90 (h Subscript[f, 0] - 34 h Subscript[f, 1] - 
        114 h Subscript[f, 2] - 34 h Subscript[f, 3] + 
        h Subscript[f, 4] + 90 Subscript[u, 3])}, 
   Subscript[u, 
    2] == {1/
      720 (-11 h Subscript[f, 0] + 74 h Subscript[f, 1] - 
        456 h Subscript[f, 2] - 346 h Subscript[f, 3] + 
        19 h Subscript[f, 4] + 720 Subscript[u, 3])}, 
   Subscript[u, 
    4] == {1/
      720 (-19 h Subscript[f, 0] + 106 h Subscript[f, 1] - 
        264 h Subscript[f, 2] + 646 h Subscript[f, 3] + 
        251 h Subscript[f, 4] + 720 Subscript[u, 3])}, 
   Subscript[u, 
    5] == {1/
      90 (29 h Subscript[f, 0] - 146 h Subscript[f, 1] + 
        294 h Subscript[f, 2] - 266 h Subscript[f, 3] + 
        269 h Subscript[f, 4] + 90 Subscript[u, 3])}};

variables = {Subscript[u, 0], Subscript[u, 1], Subscript[u, 2], 
   Subscript[u, 4], Subscript[u, 5]};

Solve[System, variables]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome, user.  People here greatly prefer that you include copyable code in your question rather than an image of a Notebook.  I can tell you from much observation that you are far more likely to receive good answers if you do.

Comment: Attempting to revise my code via code blocks, messes with the way it looks.  Unless it is displayed differently after posting?

Comment: post your code without code blocks and I shall try to edit it as I hope is appropriate.  If it is correct you can then view the post by clicking **edit** to see how it was done.

Comment: I posted the code directly from nb.   Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my request.  I formatted your code but it doesn't look too good due to the heavy use of `Subscript`.  It will however copy and paste correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying only these definitions in your code to read:

```
Subscript[K, 1] := Interval[{0, 32}];
Subscript[K, 2] := Interval[{0, 8}];
```

Produces this result:

> ```
> {Subscript[u, 0] -> Interval[{-0.09, 4.29}], 
>  Subscript[u, 1] -> Interval[{-0.0355556, 3.23556}], 
>  Subscript[u, 2] -> Interval[{-0.186667, 1.98667}], 
>  Subscript[u, 4] -> Interval[{-2.80778, 0.607778}], 
>  Subscript[u, 5] -> Interval[{-12.6578, 7.85778}]}
> ```

Does this agree with your expectation?

Comment: I just tried that method a few moments ago and received the same results.  It would seem we are in concurrence.  The results are expected, now its just a process of analyzing them.  Thank you very much for your help.